# Plot 8X8 grid between corners on part of the image

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a photo of a chessboard. I've detected the four corners of the board using YOLO, and I have their x, y coordinates.

Now I would like to plot a 8x8 grid between the four corners (along the chessboard lines).

That's a image for example:

[chessboard with corners and outer lines - original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RF4A0.jpg)

Here's my plotting code so far (python):

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as image

figure(figsize=(10, 10), dpi=80)

im = plt.imread('1.jpgresized.jpg')
implot = plt.imshow(im)

#Left
plt.plot([0.179167 * 480, 0.063542 * 480], 
         [0.203125 * 640, 0.644531 * 640], 
         'bo', linestyle="--")

#Bottom
plt.plot([0.063542 * 480, 0.934375 * 480], 
         [0.644531 * 640, 0.627344 * 640], 
         'bo', linestyle="--")

#Right
plt.plot([0.934375 * 480, 0.789583 * 480], 
         [0.627344 * 640, 0.191406 * 640], 
         'bo', linestyle="--")

#Up
plt.plot([0.789583 * 480, 0.179167 * 480], 
         [0.191406 * 640, 0.203125 * 640], 
         'bo', linestyle="--")


plt.show()
```

Comment: What are those numbers?  Is that the fractional position of the corners, from 0 to 1?  If so, then you just need lines spaced at 1/8 of the difference between the corners.  Right?

Comment: You made this more difficult for us by not providing the original image.  The image you have here is not 640x480.  It's 449x463.

Comment: Thanks, Tim. I apologize for that. I've edited the question and added the original image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does what I describe.  For each line, we create a set of 9 points evenly spaced.  Then, we draw lines from the left set to the right set, and from the top set to the bottom set.

### FOLLOWUP

I've added a hacky perspective correction on the Y coordinates.  I just do a linear adjustment.  It's not mathematically defensible, but it does the job with this image.  Doing it right would involve using the change in size from the top line to the bottom line to determine the perspective factor.  I've just hard-coded it by experimentation.

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as image

figure(figsize=(10, 10), dpi=80)

im = plt.imread('chessboard.jpg')
implot = plt.imshow(im)

W,H= 480,640

TL = (0.179167, 0.202125)
BL = (0.063542, 0.644531)
TR = (0.789583, 0.191406)
BR = (0.934375, 0.627344)

def interpolate(xy0, xy1, persp=0):
    x0,y0 = xy0
    x1,y1 = xy1
    dx = (x1-x0) / 8
    dy = (y1-y0 - persp*36) / 8
    return [(x0+i*dx,y0+i*dy+(i*(i+1)/2)*persp) for i in range(9)]

ptsT = interpolate( TL, TR )
ptsL = interpolate( TL, BL, 0.005 )
ptsR = interpolate( TR, BR, 0.005 )
ptsB = interpolate( BL, BR )

for a,b in zip(ptsL, ptsR):
    plt.plot( [a[0]*W, b[0]*W], [a[1]*H, b[1]*H], 'ro', linestyle="--" )
for a,b in zip(ptsT, ptsB):
    plt.plot( [a[0]*W, b[0]*W], [a[1]*H, b[1]*H], 'ro', linestyle="--" )

plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thanks so much, Tim! The code is fantastic! Here's the image with your code: https://ibb.co/X8sVsKW

How can I align the grid to the angle of the board on the photo?

Again, many thanks!

Comment: Ah, I didn't think about the fact that perspective would make the rows shorter as they angle away.  Let me see if it's enough to do that mathematically.

Comment: Absolutely amazing!! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @Tim you should be able to get the factor programmatically by computing the lengths of the back and front lines, then their ratio. Note that you should also recompute the ends of the horizontal lines :)

Comment: @mozway You are 100% correct on both counts.  If this were my project, or if cash were involved, I would take the time to do that.  ;)